# Assign one of multiple user-defined function to new defined function in macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file where I loop over a matrix and want to calculate something for each cell within the matrix.
I do this with the following

```
Dim x, i As Integer
For x = 1 To 10
    For i = 7 To 50
     Cells(i, x).Formula = Dummy(optionType, S, 6750, T, r, b, v)
    Next i
Next x
```

Where `Dummy` is a function that I wrote.

```
Function Dummy(optionType As String, S As Double, K As Double, T As Double, _
            r As Double, b As Double, v As Double, Optional dS)

Dummy = 1
End Function
```

However, the problem is that within the file I also specify which function I want to use within the loop. This specification is located in cell `A1`. So for example, if `A1` =  1 I want to use my own user-defined function `function_1`, 2 is my own-defined function `function_2` etc. Importantly, for each cell the function is the same. So I need to specify this before the loop. Otherwise the macro will be slower than necessary, because it checks for each cell which value is located in `A1`. I tried the methodology from this Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378306/how-to-rename-a-user-defined-function) by first using a simple dummy-variable and then run a new macro and replace the dummy-function with the specified functio. This doesn't work because the output of the `Dummy`-function is `1`.

An example of possible function is

```
Function GammaBS(optionType As String, S As Double, K As Double, T As Double, _
            r As Double, b As Double, v As Double, Optional dS)

Dim d1 As Double

d1 = (Log(S / K) + (r + v ^ 2 / 2) * T) / (v * Sqr(T))
GammaBS = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Dist(d1, False) * Exp((b - r) * T)) / (S * v * Sqr(T))

End Function
```

**Question** How can I re-use the defined functions as a new function  in a macro?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You obviously know how to call the function from another function so what do you mean by "reuse"? You can call a function from anywhere, other VBA code or even from inside a cell formula.

Comment: Sorry if I am unclear. I want to define a new function based on the value in cell A1. This new function is the same as one of the other defined functions that are out of the scope of the macro. This new function will be used for each cell in the matrix to calculate the desired output

Comment: You're assigning `Range.Formula` to an `Integer` literal - might as well assign `Range.Value` then. The question is, do you mean the function to be invoked from VBA code (as you have) or from Excel's calc engine? If the latter, then you need to assign `Range.Formula` to a string that starts with `=TheNameOfTheFunctionYouWant` (with the parameter values); that said I would warmly recommend using meaningful names for your functions, and storing their names in an array instead of encoding an index in their names.

Comment: Do all functions have a matching signature (i.e. same parameter list)?

Comment: yes, all function have the same parameter list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend writing VBA from VBA. There should be no reason to do this. You have to turn off some security settings that MS made to stop you from doing this. It's not safe.

If you just need a more dynamic formula then add more variables. Pass in the value from A1 as a parameter to the formula instead of trying to write a new formula. This will save you from corrupting your code.

```
Function GammaBS(optionType As String, S As Double, K As Double, T As Double, _
        r As Double, b As Double, v As Double, Optional dS, Optional Aone)

       If Aone = "the value you are looking for in A1" Then
           `Do the thing you want this new function to do
```

Comment: That would be a master UDF with a `Select Case` that calls the other UDFs.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and help me out! I am aware of this possibility, but this will make the loop slower right? Because then the function will check for each cell what the value in A1 is. However, this will be for each cell the same. So technically, it only needs to be checked once. Or am I incorrect?

Comment: That's much faster than attempting to write VBA from VBA, compile it and then run it. I don't know what your spreadsheet looks like and how you want it to work.